# Autofac register specific config class in generic repository

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a generic repository that I want to register with a specific config so it works kind of like a strategy pattern. This is the repository:

```
public class ConfigProvider<T> : IConfigProvider<T> where T : class 

public ConfigProvider(IConfigFilePaths filePaths)
        {
            _filePaths = filePaths;
        }
```

and those are my two config classes that are used to parametrize the ConfigProvider

```
public interface IConfigFilePaths
{
    ...
}

public class DefaultContractTypePaths : IConfigFilePaths
{
    ...
}

public class TranslationPaths : IConfigFilePaths
{
    ...
}
```

So what i would like to do on the dependencies config is something like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ConfigProvider<TranslationSet>>().As<IConfigProvider<TranslationSet>>();
builder.UseForType<ConfigProvider<TranslationSet>>().The<TranslationPaths>(); // this obviously does not work
```

Does anybody know how to tell autofac that it should use `TranslationPaths` for the `ConfigProvider<TranslationSet>` without introducing a new interface to mark the configs?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Named parameter](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html#available-parameter-types) as follows:

```
 builder
    .RegisterType<ConfigProvider<TranslationSet>>()
    .As<IConfigProvider<TranslationSet>>()
    .WithParameter("filePaths", new TranslationPaths());
```

Comment: That is something I allready did as a waorkaround. But that can not be a good practice as you have to call a constructor on your own and you can not change the parameter name without killing the config. Just imagine There are 20+ config objects and you add a parameter to the constructor. Then you would have to go and change those 20+ new calls :(

Comment: I agree it is not an ideal solution but I guess for more complex situations you will probably end up registering a factory instead